# Static chrome/firefox profile

Tags: git, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

**TL;DR**

I need to know which files in a firefox/chrome profile should be commited to have my extensions in the profile and ignore changes to the rest of the files.

---

I am making tests with Selenium that uses Chrome and Firefox profile. Both profiles has been commited inside a git repository but each time I run the tests the profiles has a lot of additions, deletes and modifications.

I want to know which files are really necessary in order to be sure that if one user use that profile will have the same behavior if other user runs the tests so I can gitignore the rest of files.

For firefox im interested only in my installed extensions and the proxy configuration. And for chrome only the installed extensions

Comment: You want same behavior to be test with fresh profiles rather than polluted profiles? You should be not looking to re-use profiles if it is related to testing. The only reason I ever re-use profiles is while doing data scraping where some existing cookies and trust level helps

Comment: I need to reuse the profile to check the behavior of the product against some extensions (in concrete, against ad blockers), if I use a fresh profile I  will have to add a step to install all the extensions for each scenario, this would make my test take a lot of time.